# Issue with CountDown Timer related to backlight off

Tags: android

I have created a Timer using the `CountDownTimer`.
Also, when the timer is 5 seconds before completion, a beep sound is played every second till it completes (comes to 0 second).

I am testing on an Android device, where I have set the Screen timeout as 15 seconds.

I found out that after the screen timeout is done, the timer pauses & doesn't complete.
Also, the sound does not play.

I am using the following code for PowerManagement / Wake lock but its not solving the issue.

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "SampleScreen");
```

However, on using the following code

```
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "SampleScreen");
```

it is working fine, but I want to avoid using the `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` which consumes a lot of battery.

The requirement is that when the screen is off, the timer should continue running & also the sound file should keep playing every second, 5 seconds before the completion of the timer.

Kindly provide your inputs/sample code on how to handle.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` instead of `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK`

Comment: I have used that code .. its provided at the above sample source code attached  ... need to scroll towards the right .. the indentation was not right

Comment: So, what happens when you use a partial wake lock? Have you added debugging statements to your activity?

Comment: When using the PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK , the timer stops after the screen time-out of the mobile device . Have used the debugging statements , it seems that the Timer component is not responding to the parameter PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to continue working when the screen time-out occurs.

Comment: That's strange, can you post where you are releasing the lock?

Comment: @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  wl.release();
 }                                                                    Am releasing the lock using the above code within the same Activity class . Kindly inform if I need to make any changes.

Comment: Did you add a debug statement to that method? What if your activity receive onPause? I have something similar in another project, but I'm starting a background service, and that service executes with a partial wake lock, and then terminates.